# Spring AOP :- Passing method parameters dynamically to advice

Tags: spring, web-services, model-view-controller, aop, spring-aop

My ServiceImpl class contains multiple methods.I have one LoggingAspect and i want to dynamically pass the method parameters to an advice based on the method called in the ServiceImpl. how do i acheive this?In the below code my method has 4 parameters,but one of my other method has 5 parametres and the third has 3.So how do i pass parameters dynamically based on number of method parameters?

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

@Before("allGenericAppServiceImplMethods(userid,galleryId,sid,imageName)")
public void LoggingAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint,String userid,String     galleryId,String sid,String imageName){
System.out.println("String values are "+userid+" "+sid+" "+galleryId+" "+imageName);
}

@Pointcut("execution(public * com.nrollup.service.impl.GenericAppServiceImpl.*(..)) && args(userid,galleryId,sid,imageName)")
public void allGenericAppServiceImplMethods(String userid,String galleryId,String sid,String imageName)
{
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the around advice for this. A code snippet for your reference:

```
public void myAdvice(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable
{
    Object[] arguments = joinPoint.getArgs();
}
```

Once you have the arguments array, you can operate upon it as required.

You can use `joinPoint.proceed()` to continue with the function call.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy!!

Comment: @FormParam("userid") String tuserid, ----> is it possible to get the name of the parameter dynamically along with the value.Since getArgs() gives me the value only and not the name which in this case is "userid"...... i m using a web service here...

Comment: Doesn't matter if you are using a web service or a simple java program. You can use AOP on anything i guess.